# Error calling payment.Create()

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

**Motivation**

I want to accept credit cards on my site. I chose PayPal because they seemed like the least hassle and not bad rates and I wanted to get up and running with accepting credit cards as quickly as possible. I chose credit card payments because I would not like my site users to go to the PayPal site; I want them to stay on my site. That looks more impressive and professional.

**What I've done**

I downloaded the `PayPal.SDK.NET451` and the `PayPal.SDK.Sample.VS.2013` from [Paypal](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/v1.7.3). I'm running with PayPal.dll version 1.7.3.0 I created a [developer account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/) on the sandbox, but for this experiment, they recommend just using the `clientId` and `clientSecret` that come with the sample project, to rule out any problems with my account or my application definition which is hosted on PayPal.

**The Issue**

In the following code, `Configuration.GetAPIContext()` and `card.Create(apiContext)` are successful. I'm tracing with Fiddler and can see 2xx responses and no exception is thrown for those calls.

However, on the call to `payment.Create(apiContext)` an exception is thrown:

```
PayPal.PaymentsException was unhandled by user code   
HResult=-2146233088   
Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.   
Response={"name":"UNKNOWN_ERROR","message":"An unknown error has occurred", "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR", "debug_id":"2ae8b36c6ea98"}   
Source=PayPal   
StackTrace:      
   at PayPal.Api.PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute[T](APIContext apiContext, HttpMethod httpMethod, String resource, String payload, String endpoint, Boolean setAuthorizationHeader) in C:\Documents\Downloads\PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\Source\SDK\Api\PayPalResource.cs:line 208      
   at PayPal.Api.Payment.Create(APIContext apiContext, Payment payment) in C:\Documents\Downloads\PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\Source\SDK\Api\Payment.cs:line 140      
   at PayPal.Api.Payment.Create(APIContext apiContext) in C:\Documents\Downloads\PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\Source\SDK\Api\Payment.cs:line 124
```

**Further Information**

There is no information in the exception to indicate why. And note this same function seems to be failing on [PayPal's developer site](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_creditcard/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox) as well! As well as failing when running from the sample application itself.

**The Code**

```cs
using PayPal.Api;
using PayPal.Sample;

protected void TestCreditCardPayment()
{
  var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();

  // First vault a credit card.
  var card = new CreditCard
  {
    expire_month = 11,
    expire_year = 2018,
    number = "4877274905927862",
    type = "visa",
    cvv2 = "874"
  };
  var createdCard = card.Create(apiContext);

  // Next, create the payment authorization using the vaulted card as the funding instrument.
  var payment = new Payment
  {
    intent = "authorize",
    payer = new Payer
    {
      payment_method = "credit_card",
      funding_instruments = new List<FundingInstrument>
    {
        new FundingInstrument
        {
            credit_card_token = new CreditCardToken
            {
                credit_card_id = createdCard.id,
                expire_month = createdCard.expire_month,
                expire_year = createdCard.expire_year
            }
        }
    }
    },
    transactions = new List<Transaction>
    {
        new Transaction
        {
            amount = new Amount
            {
                currency = "USD",
                total = "1.00"
            },
            description = "This is the payment transaction description."
        }
    }
  };
  var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how the sandbox is handling that particular card number.  You should be able to generate a new test card number using step 4 here: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1413&expand=true&locale=en_US

As long as the card passes the LUHN algorithm you should be fine and can use other test card number generators.

Comment: Earlier today I flagged my question and asked that a moderator delete the question as paypal had correctly answered the same question. I tried to delete my question but it wouldn't let me b/c there was a bounty. Ref support ticket: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/account/questions/detail/i_id/1258052